# Exception when adding a new row from the RowLeave event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have an unbound datagridview, set the option to allow user to add row to True, and all I want is that once I "complete" a row, the datagridview automatically should create a new empty row, so I set the method

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
```

in the DataGridView1_Leave event, but once the row is finished and exception comes out:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll - Unable to complete this operation in this event handler
What does it mean? It should be plain simple code, but I don't know how to solve

Here is the situation:
That's the recipient DataGridView. When I'm on the first blank row (which is created by the AllowUserToAddRow = true) and I press F3 a modal form is opened with another DataGridView containing products to select
[image: The recipient DataGridView]

and here's the code for the KeyDown event in the recipient DataGridView

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F3 Then
        If frmZoomArticoli.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                            Dim codart As String = frmZoomArticoli.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()
            RicercaxCodiceArticolo(codart)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: The child DataGridView containing products to select from]

Here the sub RicercaxCodiceArticolo(codart) which fills the recipient DataGridView with the selected product:

```
Private Sub RicercaxCodiceArticolo(ByVal codiceart As String)

    Dim strsql As String
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim source As New BindingSource

    'Dichiariamo le variabili che ospitano i dati di riga
    Dim codice As String
    Dim descrizione As String
    Dim unitamisura As String
    Dim quantita As Double = 1.0
    Dim codiceiva As Double
    Dim costobase As Double
    Dim prezzobase As Double
    Dim costoultimo As Double
    Dim giacenza As Double
    Dim sconto1 As Double
    Dim sconto2 As Double

    connection.Open()
    strsql = "SELECT CODICEARTICOLO AS 'Codice', DESCRIZIONEARTICOLO AS 'Descrizione', UNITAMISURA AS 'Um', CODICEIVA AS 'Iva' " _
            & ", COSTOBASE AS 'Costo', PREZZOBASE AS 'Prezzo', SCONTO1 As 'Sc1', SCONTO2 As 'Sc2', COSTOULTIMO AS 'CostoUlt' " _
            & ", BARCODE AS 'Barcode', NOTEARTICOLO AS 'Note' ,CATEGORIAARTICOLO AS 'Categ.Art.', GIACENZA AS 'Giacenza' " _
            & ", FORNITOREPREF AS 'Fornit. Pref.' FROM Articoli " _
            & " WHERE CODICEARTICOLO = '" & codiceart & "'"

    cmd = New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = strsql
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = connection
    source.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    'Assegniamo i dati letti nel bindingsource alle variabili
    codice = source.Current!Codice
    descrizione = source.Current!Descrizione
    unitamisura = source.Current!Um
    codiceiva = Convert.ToDouble(source.Current!Iva)
    costobase = Convert.ToDouble(source.Current!Costo)
    prezzobase = Convert.ToDouble(source.Current!Prezzo)
    costoultimo = Convert.ToDouble(source.Current!Costoult)
    giacenza = Convert.ToDouble(source.Current!Giacenza)
    sconto1 = Convert.ToDouble(source.Current!Sc1)
    sconto2 = Convert.ToDouble(source.Current!Sc2)

    'Riempiamo le celle con i dati estratti dal BindingSource
    With DataGridView1.CurrentRow
        .Cells("grdCodice").Value = codice
        .Cells("grdDescrizione").Value = descrizione
        .Cells("grdUM").Value = source.Current!Um
        .Cells("grdQuantita").Value = quantita
        If TipoMovimento = "Carico" Then
            .Cells("grdPrezzoUnitario").Value = source.Current!CostoUlt
        Else
            .Cells("grdPrezzoUnitario").Value = source.Current!Prezzo
        End If
        .Cells("grdSconto1").Value = sconto1
        .Cells("grdSconto2").Value = sconto2
        .Cells("grdSconto3").Value = 0.0
        .Cells("grdSconto4").Value = 0.0
        'Per calcolare il prezzo totale di riga dobbiamo tenere presente le
        'informazioni che abbiamo gia' in anagrafica, ovvero il costo/prezzo
        'e gli sconti

        'Blocco di controllo sul tipo movimento
        If TipoMovimento = "Carico" Then
            If sconto1 > 0 Then
                .Cells("grdPrezzoTotale").Value = quantita * (costoultimo * (costoultimo * sconto1 / 100))
            Else
                .Cells("grdPrezzoTotale").Value = quantita * costoultimo
            End If
        ElseIf TipoMovimento = "Scarico" Then
            If sconto1 > 0 Then
                .Cells("grdPrezzoTotale").Value = quantita * (prezzobase * (prezzobase * sconto1 / 100))
            Else
                .Cells("grdPrezzoTotale").Value = quantita * prezzobase
            End If
        End If

        .Cells("grdAliquotaIva").Value = codiceiva
    End With

    connection.Close()

End Sub
```

and that's the result in the recipient DataGridView:
[image: The recipient DataGridView with the selected product]

now, suppose that I don't want to edit the selected row because I don't need to edit quantity, or price, or whatever, but I just want to insert a new row to keep inserting other products. When I tab until the end of the row I want to create a new row, and that's why I wrote the DataGridView1.Rows.Add() in the RowLeave event of the DataGridView, but that's where the exception occurs:
[image: The exception when the RowLeave event fires]
I'm sorry for all the descriptions are in italian, but if you need any other details feel free to ask.
If there's nothing I can do all that remains is to add a button outside the DataGridView which adds a new row from there. Any other solution is welcomed.

Comment: With `AllowUserToAddRows = true`, the Control already shows an empty new Row at the bottom. A new one is added as soon as you start editing the previous `NewRow`. I.e., it's not clear what problem you were trying to solve in the first place.

Comment: The     AllowUserToAddRows = true allows me to have at least the first empty row apart from the row that contains headers. What I want to solve is that if user doesn't make any edit to the current row but only accepts values as they are and keeps pushing tab 'til the end of the row, when the current row is finished a new one must be created.

Comment: The `NewRow` is there all the time with `AllowUserToAddRows = true`, not just when you have no data in the grid. When users want to add new data, they just start editing a Cell and a new Row is added automatically below the previous `NewRow`. -- Do you want to simply move the `CurrentRow` to this one (the Row with `[Row]Index = [DataGridView].NewRowIndex`) on some condition? Are you trying to force users to edit some Cells? Maybe you can use the Rows and/or Cells `ErrorText` if something hasn't changed as expected? (i.e., the `DataError` event is raised or a parsing error is generated in code)

Comment: Sorry but I am not following what you describe… if the user types a “single” character into one of the “empty” cells in the grids “new” row… a “new” row is created and displayed and the cell the user typed into is no longer in the “new” row. When would you want the TAB key to create a new row? And can you demonstrate “when” a new row does not exist as expected given that the grid allows new rows to be added?

Comment: Ok I understand why you have a hard time understanding what i try to accomplish. I unintentionally omitted that the datagridview isn't fully unbound: it has no data source but receives data from a secondary datagridview, where user selects a row, and that row is transferred to the recipient datagridview. I don't have my computer ATM, but i promise I'll post some screen (and some more code) to better understand what I'm talking about. Sorry again for my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason you do not use a `DataSource` for the grid? Then you could simply add the row to the `DataSource`.

If you insist on manually adding the rows, then the problem you currently have is that the code is never “adding” a new row to the grid. The code simply uses the grids `CurrentRow` to set the values. This may work but the grids “new” row will not get created.

It is questionable to use the grids `CurrentRow` in this manner... So instead of using the grids `CurrentRow` for this, I suggest you “add” a new row in the `RicercaxCodiceArticolo` method. Something like below should add the new row and the “new-new” empty row should be at the bottom…

```
Dim newRowIndex As Int32
newRowIndex = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
With DataGridView1.Rows(newRowIndex)
    .Cells("grdCodice").Value = codice
    .Cells("grdDescrizione").Value = descrizione
    '.....
End With
```

Comment: The reason why I don't use a DataSource for my recipient DataGridView is for a lack of programming experience: I don't want to mess up all the things by using a DataSource, but maybe in the future I will fix up this part. The code you provided works just fine. Now the only thing left to fix is that when adding a new row with your method the focus goes on the new blank row below instead of remaining on the row where I called the RicercaxCodiceArticolo, but that's something I can handle. Thanks a lot.